# List Instance is not getting created correctly when deploying

Tags: 2010

No errors when deploying in Visual Studio, I can see the list.

But it should show External Site Url, External site Name and External Site Description in the ADD FORM.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you activate your feature? Do any of the components show up in the proper site galleries?

Comment: @tylerrr07 Hello, this suddenly is working, however I edited the question to reflect my problem now, its not showing correctly the fields to be edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to check/try:

1. Check the package/features to be sure all the elements files are there.
2. Are you able to manually create a list using the template?
3. Increase the TemplateType attribute, Microsoft recommends you use one greater than 10000 so as not to conflict. See: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439434.aspx)

Comment: Dont know what happen but suddenly it works for no apparent reason.  I am now concerned.

Comment: Can you please check the edit, the other problem suddenly works, so I changed the question, the ADD Form is incorrect.

Comment: I would start over, wipe away your site and try to reproduce either the working or non-working behavior a few times. It's the only way you're going to be able to trust your solution come production deployment time.